# Request Tracker Reverse Chronological Ticket History Sorting

Tags: rt

On some of our more lengthy tickets it takes awhile to load the ticket 
history when you open it.

Some of our users have request "reverse chronological" sorting so that 
they can read the latest correspondence first as they wait for the page 
to load.

> Request Tracker version 4.2.10 (latest).

Any ideas where I could make this customization?

Thanks, Michael.

Answer (score 1):

As previously said, you can set this globally on RT_SiteConfig.pm with `Set($OldestTransactionsFirst, '0');`

But in fact, the users can modify this settings in their Preferences page (section Ticket display, `Show oldest history first`).

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:

You can change the order to oldest first or oldest last using this 
setting in

> RT_SiteConfig.pm

`Set($OldestTransactionsFirst, '0');` turned off (meaning oldest is at 
the bottom of scroll. A '1' would put the most recent email (with 
attachements) and/or comments at the bottom.